# python variable not updating in function

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

```
class car():
    def __init__(self,make,model,year,fuel_capacity,perkilometer):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.fuel_capacity = fuel_capacity
        self.perkilometer = perkilometer

        self.fuel_level = 0

    def fill_tank(self):
        """fills the tank full capacity"""
        self.fuel_level = self.fuel_capacity
        print 'Tank is Full'

    def drive(self):
        """drives untill out of gas"""
        print 'car is moving'
        i = 0

        while 0 <= self.fuel_level:

            self.fuel_level -= self.perkilometer
            print '%s kilometres' % (self.fuel_level-(self.fuel_level-i))
            i+=1

        print 'out of gas'

    def travel(self,kilometer):
        """travels for distance given"""
        self.kilometer = kilometer
        print 'Car is moving'
        i=0

        while 0!=kilometer:
            kilometer-=1

            i+=1

            if self.fuel_level >= self.perkilometer:
                self.fuel_level -= self.perkilometer
                print '%s kilometres' % (kilometer - (kilometer - i))

            elif self.fuel_level < self.perkilometer:
                self.fuel_level=0
                print 'Out of Gas'
                return 0

            elif self.fuel_level == 0:
                print 'Out of Gas'
                return 0

        print 'Reached to destination'

    def continue_driving(self):
        distance_left = self.kilometer - self.fuel_level / self.perkilometer
        leters_needed = distance_left * self.perkilometer

        if distance_left<=self.fuel_level/self.perkilometer:
            print 'Have enough gas to continue'

        else:
            print 'Need %s leter more'% leters_needed


    def update_fuel_level(self,new_level):
        if  new_level <= self.fuel_capacity:
            self.fuel_level = new_level
            print 'Tank has %s leters' % self.fuel_level
        else:
            print "Tank can't hold that much"


    def add_fuel(self,amount):
        """adds fuel to gas tank"""

        if self.fuel_level+amount<=self.fuel_capacity:
            self.fuel_level+=amount
            print 'Added fuel %s leters '%amount

        else:
            print "Tank won't hold that much"

#somehow fuel level is not updating after or in add_fuel func.

my_car = car('hyundai','i20','2016','45',0.083)
my_car.fuel_level = 2
my_car.travel(50)
my_car.add_fuel(1)
my_car.continue_driving()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Car is moving
1 kilometres
2 kilometres
3 kilometres
4 kilometres
5 kilometres
6 kilometres
7 kilometres
8 kilometres
9 kilometres
10 kilometres
11 kilometres
12 kilometres
13 kilometres
14 kilometres
15 kilometres
16 kilometres
17 kilometres
18 kilometres
19 kilometres
20 kilometres
21 kilometres
22 kilometres
23 kilometres
24 kilometres
Out of Gas
Added fuel 1 leters 
Need 3.15 leter more
```

I made this car in python but when I use `continue_driving` method it seems like `fuel_level` not updating couldn't find the error.

Mainly what I am trying to achieve is calculating if gas in the tank enough or not for the ride if not to add fuel to tank.

As you can  see when I run this code it says we need 3.15 liters more but it should be 8.3/2 - (1+2) = 2.15

Comment: leters_needed doesn't take current fuel amount into account.  You need a total of 3.15 and that's what it prints.  You need to subtract the current fuel amount from it to get how much more fuel is needed.

Comment: When you ran out of gas you set self.fuel_level to 0. You then added 1 liter. Then you calculated the distance left as 50 - 1 / 0.083 ~= 38. You then calculated liters needed by 38 * 0.083 = 3.154. See my answer for more detail and a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are not tracking the distance traveled.**

You are trying to calculate your distance left based off the fuel you have consumed and your liters per kilometer.

```
distance_left = self.kilometer - self.fuel_level / self.perkilometer
```

Your code is increasing `self.fuel_level` before using it to calculate `distance_left`.

```
my_car.add_fuel(1)   # Increased self.fuel_level
my_car.continue_driving()  # Use self.fuel_level to determine distance_left
```

I recommend you track the distance traveled.

```
def __init__(self,make,model,year,fuel_capacity,perkilometer):
    self.make = make
    self.model = model
    self.year = year
    self.fuel_capacity = fuel_capacity
    self.perkilometer = perkilometer

    self.fuel_level = 0
    self.distance_traveled = 0
```

Then increment it every time you travel

```
if self.fuel_level >= self.perkilometer:
    self.fuel_level -= self.perkilometer
    self.distance_traveled += 1
    print '%s kilometres' % self.distance_traveled
```